# Accessing properties of programmatically created UIButton from within a method

Tags: iphone, uiview, methods

I have created several UI elements in the viewDidLoad method. I want to change the color of a particular UIButton from within one of my methods. How can I do this? I've tried something similar to: `self.view.myUIButton.backgroundColor = myUIColor` That doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useless you set the buttons as properties of the view controller, it loses the locally scoped  references to them when the `-viewDidLoad` method completes.

You can set the tag attribute for the buttons and then save the tags in a property. Then you can walk the viewController.view.subviews to find the subview with the right tag.

That latter is very cumbersome and shold be used only if your interface elements are highly variable.

In most cases you want something like:

```
UIButton *button1;
UIButton *button2;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  UIButton *button1;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  UIButton *button2;
```

then in viewDidLoad you would use:

self.button1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:aRect];

then in any other method you could access the specific button with `self.button1.someAttribute`

Comment: RE: tags, you can just use viewWithTag: instead of interating the subviews